# understanding I/O redirection in Unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, io-redirection

I am not sure if I fully understand Redirection in Unix. 
I was playing around with this command **" cat hello.txt world.txt > world.txt "**

The output I get is strange to me. I was guessing that world.txt will be empty initially and content of hello.txt will be stdout to world.txt.

When I run the **" cat hello.txt  world.txt >  world.txt "**
  command
and later check the content in world.txt, I see the content of hello.txt being repeatedly copied.
For eg If hello.txt has the content "Hello World!", then world.txt will print 
"Hello, world !" so many times like hundreds of lines.

**Any reason why this happens**
thank you

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of redirection is fine; it's your understanding of `cat` that is lacking. Your implementation of `cat` writes the contents of `hello.txt` to `world.txt` (which was indeed empty when `cat` *started* due to the redirection), then goes into the following loop:

1. Read from `world.txt`.
2. If no data was found, exit
3. Write data to `world.txt`,
4. GOTO 1

POSIX doesn't require such a loop; `cat` could (I think) simply read the entire contents of `world.txt` first, write it out to standard output, then exit without checking if `world.txt` has grown. But I suspect no implementation would ever actually do that, for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

First, `cat` will open `hello.txt` and effectivley copy its contents to `world.txt` due to redirection.  What's going to happen next however, is that `cat` will open `world.txt`, which is now a copy of `hello.txt`.  As `cat` reads data from `world.txt`, it redirects its output to the designated file (i.e., `world.txt`), meaning there's always more to read (assuming infinite disk).